# Versioning with Visual Studio 2010 and HG

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, version-control, mercurial, projects-and-solutions

Recently me and my team got a HG repository for versioning as this would make it easier and better to develop our application.

We are using Visual Studio 2010 and c#

All of the project is under version control..

Unfortunately, when one of us commits, usually the other gets an error of some kind when opening the solution (due to the various files VS has)

My question is: what files should be put under version control? (and removed in my case!)

PS: we have 3 Projects: (using XNA) game, contents, test

Thank you very much!!!

Dan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least you need these in your `.hgignore`:

```
syntax: glob
bin
obj
*.sln.cache
*.suo
*.user
```

Add as needed. But don't overignore as you can lose data that way. For instace @Darin's answer causes you to stop tracking of private key files (.snk).

Comment: This is way too short - what happens when you use MS test? You don't want to save those result files. You don't want PEM keys, SQL binary backups, you don't want resharper files, all form of log files and so on. This will work fine, but it's the barest of bare and will result in a user groaning when they realize "Oh CRAP - dude why is our 50Mb BAK file going in!".

Comment: Rob I am against any assumptions about what people use. That's why I provided a minimal set. I believe `.hgignore` should be built consciously, not blindly. That's why I said "add as needed". VS by default does not produce any of the files you mentioned. If we built .hgignore files based on the possibility of what tools people might use and which files they might generate in the future, the .hgignore would be very big, unmaintainable, and can actually cause needed files to slip out, which is way worse than superfluous files in your source control.

Answer (score 2):

I use below and it came from Rob Conery on his tutorials for mercurial (http://tekpub.com/view/hg/1 & http://tekpub.com/codeplex) at tekpub.  It's on a git repo and was originally for VS 2K8 but works just fine for 2K10.  http://gist.github.com/314082

syntax: glob

```
*.obj 
*.exe 
*.pdb 
*.user 
*.aps 
*.pch 
*.vspscc 
*_i.c 
*_p.c 
*.ncb 
*.suo 
*.tlb 
*.tlh 
*.bak 
*.cache 
*.ilk 
*.log 
*.lib 
*.sbr 
*.scc 
[Bb]in 
[Dd]ebug*/ 
obj/ 
[Rr]elease*/ 
_ReSharper*/ 
[Tt]est[Rr]esult* 
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.* 
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
```

Comment: This is overkill. Why don't you just ignore bin and obj folders?

Comment: @ssg - This may sound odd but thanks for the vote down as its got me thinking. I haven't given the ignore file much thought before & your question got me thinking which is great! I have thoughts as to why it may or may not be overkill but before answering I think I need to do more thinking/learning on it. :-)

Comment: This is an ignore file, meant to maintain the usability of your repo and, in some cases, the integrity of your working copy.  It's not some kind of pack you have to carry around that gets heavier the more you put in it.  Why look down your nose at the hard work someone else did to separate the wheat from the chaff so you didn't have to?  I can tell you from experience, this is the best list so far in this post.

Comment: @ssg the /bin and /debug files are ignored as you can see, but Visual Studio adds in a bunch of other "noise" files, which are detailed here. Those files include test results, logs, XML file for publishing, cache, SQL Server backup, user file (suo etc), debug symbols, and so on.

Comment: Also - when you have an ignore file there is no such thing as overkill.

Comment: @Binary: see my comment in reply to Rob in my answer.

Comment: @Rob: I find several things wrong with this file:

1) It assumes the developer is a C/C++ developer and blindly ignores related extensions which might actually be relevant to a .NET developer. (say a data file with an extension of ".ilk"). A .NET developer might lose data because of this during the development.

2) It assumes developer will put build output into the source code folder which is just hack around a bad practice. I don't think an ignore file is for that.

3) It will ignore TestResult.cs / TestResult.c file which SHOULD NOT be ignored.

Comment: 4) Similarly it will ignore BuildLog.cs / BuildLog.c, my build log classes for my project which also should NEVER be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of files and directories I exclude from version control in the case of directory I exclude recursively everything from this directory):

```
bin/
obj/
TestResults/
*.vspscc
*.user
*.snk
*.suo
*.vssscc
*.gpState
Debug/
Release/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more:

```
*.ncb
*.sdf
*.ilk
*.aps
*.resharper
_ReSharper*
*.Cache
```