# Mercurial [HG] - Get the list of .hgignore excluded files

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgignore

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233274/11545) `.hgignore` file liberally in my projects, it has proven worthy so far.

However, every once in a while I'd like to do a reality check, to make sure it didn't eat up something valuable.

My question is: how can I find out the exact list of excluded files? (The files that actually match the `.hgignore` patterns)

Answers using TortoiseHg or command-line are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `hg status --ignored` (or `hg status -i`) lists the files that have been ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The answer hit me while I was finishing the question (yet again).

It's trivial, actually:

- Start by making sure there are no pending commits.
  [image]
- (Re)move/rename the `.hgignore` file
- Hit 'Refresh' in TortoiseHg's commit window.
  [image]

You'll now get the exact list of ignored files (+ the change to the `.hgignore` file itself).

Rubber ducking at its best. (Hmm, SO should add a badge for this :)